# Error after upgrading to NHibernate 3.0 XML parsing: line 1, character 4000, unexpected end of input

Tags: nhibernate

I have a sql2008 db that has a column type of xml.
Using NHibernate 2.5 I can save to this column no problems.

I've dropped in the NHibernate 3.0 dlls and suddenly I'm getting the above errors?

My mapping file doesn't have a type against that column so surely NHibernate should pick up the xml data type (I'm using the sql 2008 dialect) ?

4000 just seems to be a suspicious length, i.e the length of a varchar column in sql.

I see there are a few articles about mapping xml columns using custom UserTypes, etc.

How come this just worked in 2.5 and now doesn't in 3.0 ? I don't need any special handling. That column gets used as a string everywhere.

Comment: What's the property type? what are your mappings? What's the FULL exception?

Comment: I have no property type in my mapping file. Just the column name and the property name. I know that NHIbernate 3 now offers native support for XmlDocument by declaring the type as xml in the mapping file. But we use the column as a string everywhere and deserialize it into a business object when needed (its passed to various Java web services as a string at various points)

Answer (score 3):

The reason this behavior changed from 2.x to 3.0.0 was due to [a code commit](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/commit/03eb58acae867e2d5620446c3b07cb91e7d74422) on `NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver`, which effectively turned on some of the behavior of enabling the `prepare_sql` configuration in order to resolve an [issue with the caching of query plans](http://testdrivendevelopment.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/nhibernate-queries-sql-server-execution-plans/).

A C# `string` property mapped to a column that has no other `type` specified in its mapping will get treated as a `NHibernate.SqlTypes.StringSqlType` and given a 4000 character limit by the driver:

From `NHibernate.SqlTypes.StringSqlType`:

> ```
> /// <remarks>
> /// This can store the length of the string that the <see cref="IDbDataParameter"/> can hold.
> /// If no value is provided for the length then the <c>Driver</c> is responsible for
> /// setting the properties on the <see cref="IDbDataParameter"/> correctly.
> /// </remarks>
> ```

So, you can see that the code below from the driver (`NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver`), maps a default `string` property to a length of 4000 characters.

```cs
/* SNIP */
private const int MaxAnsiStringSize = 8000;
private const int MaxBinarySize = MaxAnsiStringSize;
private const int MaxStringSize = MaxAnsiStringSize / 2;
private const int MaxBinaryBlobSize = int.MaxValue;
private const int MaxStringClobSize = MaxBinaryBlobSize / 2;

/* SNIP */
private static void SetDefaultParameterSize(IDbDataParameter dbParam, SqlType sqlType)
{
    switch (dbParam.DbType)
    {
        /* SNIP */
        case DbType.String:
        case DbType.StringFixedLength:
            dbParam.Size = IsText(dbParam, sqlType) ? MaxStringClobSize : MaxStringSize;
            break;
        /* SNIP */
        }
    }
```

*For configurations with `prepare_sql` set to `false`, NH 3.0.0 now brings the `SetDefaultParameterSize` method into play where it was not before*

As you noted, you can use NH-3.0.0-native support for the SQL Server `XML` datatype (thanks to NH-866), like so:

```xml
<property name="Data" type="xml" not-null="true" />
```

*or more explicitly, but equivalently:*

```xml
<property name="Data" type="XmlDoc" not-null="true">
  <column name="DATA" sql-type="XmlSql" />
</property>
```

But using `NHibernate.Type.XmlDocType` expects the property type to be of C# type `XmlDocument` - leading to a cast exception.

You could do the `XmlDocument.InnerXml` fix like you mentioned, but that's a lot of unnecessary transformation from string to doc and back. I've used the following mapping to keep the domain property a string:

```
<property name="Data" type="StringClob" not-null="true">
  <column name="DATA" sql-type="XmlSql" />
</property>
```

*Using `NHibernate.Type.StringClobType` will return true for the `IsText(dbParam, sqlType)` call in the driver snippet above, giving a max character length of `int.MaxValue / 2` - something like 2GB of string data.*

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the property type to xml in the mapping file.

Then just used the XmlDocument that is returned as XmlDocument.InnerXml to get the string value.